How to reply to "hope you all had a great time celebrating"
It was my grandma's birthday and my aunt texted us saying "hope you all had a great time celebrating" how to reply to that

What is the problem.  Do you understand "great time" and "hope"?

"Yes, we did, thanks" (assuming you did have a good time!). What else?

I’m voting to close this question because open-ended writing advice isn't a good fit here. If you're having trouble understanding the text, please edit to explain more.

Don't overthink it.
You could write a short text saying how much you enjoyed the birthday:

I had a great time, thanks.  We had cake and danced to old records.

